# Find a specific values in column and take few next elements that are next to it

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, apply

I have a problem with one task. I have a list of values that looks like below:

```
values = ["a","b","c"]
```

and my DF looks like below:

```
column_1 column_2
1        sffasdef
2        bsrewsaf
3        tyhvbsrc
4        ertyui1c
5        qwertyyu
```

I have to check if one of values in list exists in column 2. If there is, in new column it should return result and next 3 elements, so the DF should look like below:

```
column_1 column_2  column_3
1        sffasdef  asde
2        bsrewsaf  bsre
3        tyhvbsrc  bsrc
4        ertyui1c  c
5        qwertyyu  NaN
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.str.extract`:

```
df['column_3'] = df['column_2'].str.extract(f'((?:{"|".join(values)})(?:.?){{3}})')

# OR, possibly more readable

values_re = '|'.join(values)
df['column_3'] = df['column_2'].str.extract(r'((?:' + values_re + ')(?:.?){3})')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   column_1  column_2 column_3
0         1  sffasdef     asde
1         2  bsrewsaf     bsre
2         3  tyhvbsrc     bsrc
3         4  ertyui1c        c
4         5  qwertyyu      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have single characters in `values`:

```
df['column_3'] = df['column_2'].str.extract(fr'([{"".join(values)}].{{,3}})')
```

output:

```
   column_1  column_2 column_3
0         1  sffasdef     asde
1         2  bsrewsaf     bsre
2         3  tyhvbsrc     bsrc
3         4  ertyui1c        c
4         5  qwertyyu      NaN
```